# sort something in given order and then sort the rest

Tags: r, sorting

I have

```
q<-c("1","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17",
 "18","19","20","21","22","GL000205.1","GL000205.2","2","3","4","5","6",
 "7","8","9","GL000205.1","X","Y","M")
```

I want to sort them as

```
q<-c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11",
 "12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20",
 "21","22","X","Y","M","GL000205.1","GL000205.2")
```

I used

```
chrOrder <-c((1:22),"X","Y","M")
indata[,chrom.pos]<- factor(indata[,chrom.pos], chrOrder,ordered=TRUE)
```

This sorts the data, but turns GL000205.1 and GL000205.2 into blank. I want to restore everything and sort them in chr1,2,3,,.... order. I took above approach as I know about chr 1,2,,.... Y,M before hand. I dont have information about other chromosome.
It would be more efficient if I dont have to provide any order before hand(chrOrder) as in that case there wont be any chance of loosing any information.
I was thinking to put some wild card in the end of chrmOrder, which would allow to put rest of the chromosome in the end.

EDITED:
If I have q

```
q<-c("1","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17",
 "18","19","20","21","22","GL000205.1","GL000205.2","2","3","4","5","6",
 "7","8","9","GL000205.1","23","24","25")
```

The given solution would work fine but would also return "X","Y","M". 
Is it possible to sort in order whatever I have in "q" and dont return "X","Y""M"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want those of 1:22, X, Y, and M that appear in `q` to be part of the levels, you can define `chrOrder` as

```
chrOrder <-intersect(c((1:22),"X","Y","M"),q)
chrOrder <-c(chrOrder,sort(setdiff(q, chrOrder)))
```

The second line is equivalent to the second line of Codoremifa's answer; the first keeps only the part of the set [1:22, X, Y, M] that are also in `q`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but why not define chrOrder as below?

```
chrOrder <-c((1:22),"X","Y","M")
chrOrder <-c(chrOrder,sort(unique(q[!q %in% chrOrder])))
```